# How to return a boolean for whether or not a QUrl redirects?

Tags: c++, qt, http, redirect, qnetworkaccessmanager

I have been playing around with this, and I can not quite follow the logic for redirections in qt. Really, all I would like to do is build a function like so:

```
bool MyClass::isRedirect(const QUrl &url)
{
        return QUrl(m_NetworkAccessManager.get(QNetworkRequest(url))
        ->header(QNetworkRequest::LocationHeader).toString()).toString()
        != url.toString();
}
```

And for proof of concept, I'd like it done with this url:

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vario-Tessar

It should redirect to:

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tessar#Vario-Tessar

I figure this should be really easy, but the answer is evading me. I tried putting in the url, and checking the reply for a header indicating a redirect, but none came up. Reading the documentation... it took me for a loop as I could not quite grasp if I am supposed to set an attribute on the `QNetworkReply`, `QNetworkRequest`, or the `QNetworkAccessManager` itself for allowing redirects, and then afterwards, constructing a boolean.

I am also not sure if every redirect is the same, or if some pages implement it differently, having a script run after page load, like this:

> https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Vario%20Tessar&action=edit

If I really wanted to, I could use a `QWebEngineView` to load, and just compare before and after urls, but that seems a bit hefty. I just want the simplest way to perform that function above.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest to look at the **http status code of the reply**, this way:

```
int http_code = reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute).toInt();
```

In your example it happens to be `200` (OK), i.e. no redirection at all.

Anyway, if you invoke

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vario-Tessar

(notice the missing *s* in the protocol name) a redirection will occur.

Given that the manager and/or the request are using the default redirect policy  (`QNetworkRequest::ManualRedirectPolicy`), the response will sport a status code of *301*, this time, and no data. Moreover you can check the redirection target:

```
int code = reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute).toInt();
static QVector<int> redirectCodes{301, 302, 303, 305, 307, 308};
if(redirectCodes.contains(code))
{
    QUrl redirectUrl = reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::RedirectionTargetAttribute).toUrl();
    //...
```

At this point, you could start a new request using the redirect target, or abort the transaction altogether, or whatever your own personal redirect policy suggests you.

If you just don't want to deal with redirection at all, you can set a different policy at manager level, using [`QNetworkAccessManager::setRedirectPolicy`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#setRedirectPolicy), or at request level, using [`QNetworkRequest::setAttribute`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkrequest.html#setAttribute).